# Is it possible to create a type alias of a class's typedef, that acts like a member of the class in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry for the title, the question is hard to compose.

I am using C++11's std::initializer_list in my project and have made a type alias for it, to match the type naming convention I'm using (CamelCase):

```
namespace Core
{
    template<typename T>
    using InitialiserList = std::initializer_list<T>;
}
```

I may be going too pedantic, but I'd also like to make type aliases for `std::initializer_list`'s iterators, e.g: `ConstIterator` for `const_iterator`.

I know I can do it like this:

```
template<typename T>
using ILConstIterator = std::initializer_list<T>::const_iterator;

// Usage
ILConstIterator<int> it;
```

but I'd like to use it as:

```
Core::InitialiserList<T>::ConstIterator it;
```

Is this possible in a not-too-messy way?

Comment: doesnt `ILConstIterator it;` need to be `ILConstIterator<int> it;` etc, since you need to know which type to pass to initializer_list?

Comment: Why would you want to change the names of standard types?

Comment: Added the missing template argument. @Barry to use the same naming convention throughout the project.

Comment: Never force a programming language on Procrustes bed: That will just result in a bloody mess. Just follow the languages style.

Comment: This is a recipe for confusion for whomever has to maintain the code.

Comment: `#define ConstIterator const_iterator`. I dare you.